# Missing team channel despite a successful HTTP call to create channel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm testing add Teams, Channels, messages and replies to get the different errors the Graph API returns.

Once I did a Post Channel on [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/[teamID]/channels](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%5BteamID%5D/channels) .
I got a 201 Created response that contained the Channel ID.
When I tried to add anything to that Channel (tabs or messages), I would get a 404 Not Found.
I checked in the Team and the General channel logged that the channel was added.
I could see it in the list of hidden channels but once I clicked show, it would disappeared.

I created hundreds of channels afterward without reproducing this issue.
I usually get a 502 Bad gateway, "Failed to execute backend request" when there's an issue.
Still, I wanted to log that it's rare but possible to get a false 201 Created with the Graph API.

I was running Fiddler when it happened. Here's a screenshot of the calls:
[Fiddler screenshot of the false 201 Created response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkjzT.png)

Edit: Here's a gif of the Channel in Team: [Created Channel that disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtSlF.gif)

Comment: Don't MS provide their own bug-tracking system for such things? SO is not a bug-logging service.

Comment: We could not repro the issue on our side. Could you please share the request/response when this happens next?